# Add Question in Discussion board with attachment using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, discussion-board, attachments

I am trying to add a Question to a discussion board with a file attachment using REST API.

I am able to add other data in discussion list, but I am not able to attach a file inside it.

How can this be done?

Comment: You need two requests. First request, add item and in second request ,add attachment.

Comment: i know , but attachement is uploaded in document library. and if i insert file form web manually then it attached in document lib. but it also create link in body column.